# Spotfire help! Trying to manually plot "regression" line on top of bar chart. Is there a way to manually input data points?

Tags: regression, data-analysis, spotfire

Am creating a bar chart in spotfire and would like to plot a line on top of the chart that acts as a trend line but need to manually enter the data points. Is there a way to do so? Have not found any documentation on such thing. Would really appreciate some help with this!! Thanks!

Comment: Are the points going to change?

Comment: No the points will not change, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the points will be static, I would put the points in a column in excel and embed the data into your analysis. Then you can change your chart type to combination (line and bar) and plot your newly added data as a line.

You will need a column in both tables which will be used as the relation and set up the relation via Edit > Data Table Properties > Relations.

Relations are like keys to link two separate data sources. In database terms, it's a KEY.  For example, take a look at [THIS MODEL](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Relational_Model.svg/543px-Relational_Model.svg.png). These tables are related based off the Activity Code.

Here are some other helpful references.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/md/md_working_with_data_tables.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model

Comment: Could you explain the relation column a little more?

Comment: @RahatSyed i added some explanation of relations in the answer.

Comment: No worries @RahatSyed. Be sure to upvote answers that are helpful on all of your questions, and accept those that are correct. Good Luck.

Comment: It won't let me upvote, not enough reputation haha! But yes your solution worked, I have configured my db a bit though to include a data table with static data that I had. I am having a problem plotting the new curve on top main data table. Have you encountered this problem?

Comment: Click the check box under the voting to accept the answer byt i'm glad it worked! :) @RahatSyed

Comment: I haven't had the curve problem, you should post a new question with it though!